# Mysql order by 2 columns that represent price and new price

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have 2 columns for a product `price` that represents the normal price and `new_price` that represents the offer of the product. When I order them by price I can't get a correct order if both columns are filled. Now it orders first by new price and then by price. I want somehow to concatenate prices.

```
if($order==1)
{
    $order_by='Produse.New_price ASC,Produse.Price ASC';
}

if($order==2)
{
    $order_by='Produse.New_Price DESC,Produse.Price DESC';
}    

if($order==3)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod ASC';
}   

if($order==4)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod DESC';
}   

if($order==0)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod DESC';
}
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("Select * FROM Produse 
                               INNER JOIN Categorii on Produse.ID_Categorie=Categorii.ID_Categorie 
                             where Categorii.Nume_Categ=:id 
                             ORDER BY $order_by");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: use coalesce to return the first non-null price in new price vs price... `order by coalesce('Produse.new_price, produse.price)`  This assumes that when both are present you want to order by new price.  and new price is null you want to order by just the price.

Comment: depends what you want... `order by new_price+price DESC` `order by IF(new_price IS NOT NULL, new_price, price) DESC` or simply order just by one column because for me it doesn't make sense at all ;)

Comment: What does "somehow concatenate prices" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Coalesce to sort by new price if present (not null) then by price if new price is null...

```
if($order==1)
{
    $order_by='coalesce(Produse.New_price,Produse.Price) ASC';
}
if($order==2)
{
    $order_by='Coalesce(Produse.New_Price,Produse.Price) DESC';
}    
if($order==3)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod ASC';
}   
if($order==4)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod DESC';
}   
if($order==0)
{
    $order_by='Produse.Nume_Prod DESC';
}
        $stmt=$dbh->prepare("Select * FROM Produse 
                               INNER JOIN Categorii on Produse.ID_Categorie=Categorii.ID_Categorie 
                             where Categorii.Nume_Categ=:id 
                             ORDER BY $order_by");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```